# How to totally remove Ubuntu and install Lubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, uninstall

I've Asus computer with 2x Intel Celeron CPU 1000M @ 1.80 Ghz. 
I've installed Ubuntu 16 on my computer but it seems too heavy for it. When computer is opening sometimes it takes 5 minutes to prepare desktop and when I click on any application again it takes something like 4-5 minutes to run application.

Thusly I've decided to uninstall Ubuntu and install Lubuntu instead of it which is more lighweight. I got all personel folder to somewhere else and burned a Lubuntu ISO to USB stick.

Now I want to totally remove Ubuntu and all additional softwares which I've downloaded to computer and then make a clean install of Lubuntu. But I can not remove the Ubuntu.

I've checked internet and on every blog says something different. Finally I've run `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and now I can switch to Lubuntu but still computer to slow. As well whole pre-installed softwares are exist.

How can I achieve for a totally clean re-install of Ubuntu and installing a clean Lubuntu instead of it?

Comment: To clean install Lubuntu, you need only boot it and install it (a perfectly clean system is achieved with formatting).  How much ram do you actually have, as the times you gave seem excessive for your cpu (longer than a 1.5gb single-core pentium m i have [at slower clock rate])

Comment: @guiverc On Bios Boot Menu I've two Boot Option Priorities but both says `ubuntu (PO: ST320LT...)`. I think computer can not reach Lubuntu ISO burned USB then, right?

Comment: Every blog says something different because you probably forget to mention some vital information like the RAM amount (as someone already asked) of your PC. Keep in mind that installed but unused software does not make your PC slower so a clean reinstall would probably not resolve your problem. If low on RAM, try to expand it instead of reinstalling. If the amout of RAM is enough (say 2GB) then try some lighter desktop (but lubuntu is one of the lightest) as probably other factors come to play (as video card performance).

Comment: @ciampix OK this explanation become more understable for me. I've 4GB on my computer -i guess!. I just run `free -m` on terminal and response as: `Mem: Total 3831, used 1620, free 534, shared: 355, buff/cache 1676, available 1573`. So it should be OK depends on your comment. But still my computer quite slow.

Comment: I don't know your bios settings, nor how to read the ubuntu (PO:seagate....) so can't help. Usually somewhere in bios there is a boot-order I'd ensure pointed to USB-external (or like), or press <f9> (or other key; *<esc> on my asus eeepc*) so i get asked which device to boot.

Comment: Ok you have a decent CPU and a huge amount of RAM. You probably are running Linux in 64bit ... definitely you have some problem here. Probably your hard-drive is failing and that slowness is due to the attempt to read some sectors. If you can, look for a "disk" application (the real app name if you type it in a terminal is "gnome-disks") then go to the top right icon and look for the S.M.A.R.T. info to exclude or confirm this problem. I suggest you also to do a (long) disk test: anyway it does not hurt. If you have some spare money, buy a small SSD disk and your laptop will fly.

Comment: @ciampix thanks for this advice. As you told I've ran on 64bit Ubuntu. Now firstly I'l do this Disk test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have over came on issue which avoid me to format whole OS through BIOS settings . I had burned Lubuntu ISO to USB but couldn't see USB because of **Secure Boot Mode** was enable.

I've disabled it and then saw the Lubuntu installer USB on *Boot Options* and be succedd to totally removing Ubuntu, installing Lubuntu instead of it.

Thanks for @ciampix and @guiverc for their comments.

Comment: Kindly paste this text as a comment rather than a proper answer.

Comment: @mAnN This answer is not only for 'thanks'. Of course their suggestions helped me to find solution but the solution was totaly different than suggestions. So I'm giving the 'answer' of solution as main purpose.